# How to extract data from dropdown list on a web page and print in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, web

Below is my code, Can anyone please let me know how to write the values in excel by extracting it from webpage using python, i am able to print all the months in my pycharm console by using the below code.

****PYTHON CODE:****

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

Birthday=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("month"))
Monthlist=Birthday.options
for options in Monthlist:
    A=options.text
    print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/) for create excel file in python.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('options.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for index, options in enumerate(Monthlist):
    worksheet.write(f'A{index + 1}', options.text)

workbook.close()
```

following code for save in columns :

```
 import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('options.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for index, options in enumerate(Monthlist):
    worksheet.write(0,index, options.text)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Hi ahmad thank you very much for your response, yea it is working, can this code be written if we want to print the values in column rather in row, Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thanks for that again,but the problem here for me is i already have the data in the first column of the excel and i wanted this data to be in the second column of the same excel and validate both rows and wanted the result in third row......but with the present code it is overwriting the data present in the excel, Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Hi. `xlsxwriter` module only can create xlsx workbook. if you want to modify excel file you can use `openpyxl` module follow this [tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)